# Generate random points from a raster with a pre-established distance between the points in R

Tags: r, spatial, r-raster

I want to generate random points over a raster, but I need these points to have a distance between them, like 10000 meters. I've seen that is possible to establish distance between points using the package 'spatstat', but I didn't understand how to use this package to generate points based on a raster.

This is what I did to generate the points without the distance criteria:

```
#Number of points
n.points = 63

#Generate random points from a raster
sampling = raster::sampleRandom(myraster,size=63,na.rm=TRUE,
                       cells=FALSE,xy=TRUE,sp=FALSE,asRaster=FALSE)

#Select just the coordinates and transform in a data frame
xy = as.data.frame(sampling[,c(1,2)])

#Spatialize these points
spdf = sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = xy,
                                  data = as.data.frame(xy),
                                  proj4string = 
                                    CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean for 63 points to have a 10000m distance between them.  Do you mean the closest other point to each one is exactly 10000m away, or at least 10000m away, or something else?

Comment: Thank you for the answering. The first option, the closest other point to each one is exactly 10000m away. This is important because I will draw different sizes of buffers around these points and they can't overlap each other.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that tries to select points according to your rule that the closest point to any point is exactly 10000m from it.  This code ignores any issues of map projection and curvature of the Earth; that should be fine in a relatively small area, but not over a very large one.

```r
r <- 10000   # distance between points
n.points <- 63

x <- matrix(NA, nrow = n.points, ncol = 2)

# Sample one point randomly in the region.  I'll assume the region is
# +/- 100000 in each coordinate; if your region is some other shape,
# change this code:

x[1,] <- runif(2, -100000, 100000)

for (i in 2:n.points) {
  # Count how many tries to find the next point
  tries <- 0   
  repeat {
    # Pick an existing point
    j <- sample(1:(i-1), 1)
    
    # Pick a direction from it
    theta <- runif(1, 0, 2*pi)
    
    # Find the point at distance r in that direction
    y <- x[j,] + r*c(cos(theta), sin(theta))
    
    # Is the point in the region?
    if (any(y < -100000) || any(y > 100000))
      next
    
    # Calculate the distances to all other points
    dists <- apply(x[1:(i-1), , drop=FALSE], 
                   1, 
                   function(row) sqrt(sum((row - y)^2)))
    
    # If this point is far enough from existing points, keep it
    if (all(dists >= r))
      break
    
    # If not, try again, but not forever...
    tries <- tries + 1
    if (tries > 100000)
      stop("failed")
  }
  x[i,] <- y
}
plot(x)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>